# External devices support in android

Tags: android, android-camera, apk

Is this possible to use external camera or other devices like fingure print scanners kind of devices in android. Is this possible to access those devices in an android application programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

**USB Host and Accessory**

Android supports a variety of USB peripherals and Android USB accessories (hardware that implements the Android accessory protocol) through two modes: USB accessory and USB host.

[link here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html)

[USB Accessory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html)